# Unable to give access to custom action using cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have Blog Controller and Model and i want to give access to a custom action my ability model is like this:

```
user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
  if user.has_role? :admin
    can :manage, :all
  elsif user.has_role? :creator
    can :progress, Blog
    can :read, :all
    can :manage, Blog
  else 
    can :read, :all
  end
```

and in my progress action i am authorizing user like this

```
authorize! :progress, current_user
```

But it always give me authorized user error.

```
You are not authorized to access this page.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ability file looks fine, except that "manage" means all, so your can :progress, Blog like is fully covered by your can :manage, Blog line

The authorize! call in your progress action should however not have current_user as second parameter, but the object you want to check access for, e.g. @blog, or something like that

Have a look at https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions for more details!